# php composer.phar update does not work with Symfony install

Tags: windows, symfony, wamp, composer-php

I'm running WAMP on Windows 7 64 Bits.
The `PATH` variable is set to `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\`

I'm trying to install Symfony and I do not understand why first line runs and not the second:

This runs successfully:

```
php c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\composer.phar update
```

This line fails:

```
php composer.phar update
```

With the error:

> "Could not open input file: composer.phar"

What can explain this?

`get_include_path` returns : `

> .;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php\PEAR`.

Does this mean that if composer.phar is not in PEAR directory 'php composer.phar update' will not work?

Comment: I don't think `php blabla` will request the path variable to find `blabla` somewhere.

Comment: This works for me in wamp:
> composer update package-name

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try this instead:

> composer.phar update

Why would php be aware of your $PATH variable?

Plus, I think $PATH is only used by your shell when dealing with the first word of your command line.

Comment: So I need to put `composer.phar` in `$PATH` variable

Comment: If you try what I suggested, yes. Another solution would probably be `php ./composer.phar update`

Comment: I want to know why the second line does not run.

Comment: Then you need to now if your current working directory is in php's (cli version) include path . You may use `get_include_path()` in cli to know that.

Comment: `get_include_path` returns : `.;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php\PEAR`. Means that if composer.phar is not in PEAR directory 'php composer.phar update' couldn't works ?

Comment: the `.` at the beginning of your include_path means "current working directory", so no, it should really work. Maybe something in the phar resets your include_path to something else?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17705/discussion-between-manu-and-greg0ire)

Comment: REMOVE `.phar`. In my case, I had already installed composer for windows, thus not needing to run `composer.phar`. This is the command that worked for me `composer update`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 10):

Command `composer self-update` will do the trick. 
 For example:

1. goto cmd and jump into your project folder if in case 
    `c:\wamp\www\{yourprojectfolder}`
    as your project
2. Run this 
   `cd c:\wamp\www\{yourprojectfolder}`
3. Use this 
   `composer self-update`

Answer (score 4):

You should logout and then login or restart in order to changes in path becomes available.

Comment: In fact, on Windows, you only have to restart (or get a new) the command line window to get the PATH up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

Okay this is how i solved it.

1. Download and install git bash
2. open git bash
3. run composer selfupdate or composer self-update

cheers hope this helps you too.

Comment: On *Windows* if you're a developer who distills things (removes dependencies and loathes third party code) then to run Composer the git bash bit worked! Thank you for existing.