# The requested URL was not found on this server but works local

Tags: php, laravel, docker, apache2

I have a Laravel setup where I can add files and remove them. Now when I try to remove icons on my site on the server I get

```
Not Found
The requested URL /icons/24 was not found on this server.
```

Uploading the files and retrieving the files works. When I test it locally it works. And I do it the exact same way as with images, video files and audio files, and those all work on the server.

To debug it I also added the `show()` function in the controller, and that one also gives the same problem. What is going on?

routes/web.php: (partially)

```
Route::get('iconFile/{id}','IconController@iconFile');
Route::get('imageFile/{id}','ImageController@imageFile');
Route::get('audioFile/{id}','AudioController@audioFile');
Route::get('videoFile/{id}','VideoController@videoFile');
Route::get('signlanguageFile/{id}','SignlanguageController@signlanguageFile');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::post('image-upload-with-validation',['as'=>'postimage','uses'=>'ImageController@postImage']);
    Route::post('icon-upload-with-validation',['as'=>'posticon','uses'=>'IconController@postIcon']);

    Route::resource('texts', 'TextController');
    Route::resource('icons', 'IconController');
    Route::resource('images', 'ImageController');
    Route::resource('videos', 'VideoController');
    Route::resource('signlanguages', 'SignlanguageController');
    Route::resource('audios', 'AudioController');
});
```

IconController:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Icon;
use Storage;

class IconController extends Controller
{

    public function iconFile($id)
    {
        $icon = Icon::find($id);
        $contents = Storage::disk('local')->get('uploads/icons/'.$icon->file);
        $response = Response($contents);
        $response->header('Content-Type', 'icon');
        return $response;
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $icon = Icon::find($id);
        $data = [
            'icon' => $icon
         ];
         echo $icon;
        //return view('icon', $data);
    }

    public function postIcon(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'icon_file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:10000',
        ]);
        $iconName = time().'.'.$request->icon_file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $request->icon_file->move(storage_path('app/uploads/icons'), $iconName);

        $icon = new Icon;
        $icon->parent_id = $request->parent_id;
        $icon->file = $iconName;
        $icon->save();

        return back()
            ->with('success','You have successfully uploaded an icon.')
            ->with('icon',$iconName);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $icon = Icon::find($id);
        $section_id = $icon->parent_id;
        Storage::delete('uploads/icons/'.$icon->file);
        $icon->delete();
        return redirect('/section/'.$section_id)->with('success','Icon deleted.');
    }
}
```

**Update:**

i tried replacing the resource route to `Route::resource('iconz', 'IconController');` (with a z) and then it works! Changing it back to "icons" makes it stop working again. Could icons be some kind of reserved word?

Also tried `php artisan route:clear` which didn't help.

Comment: I feel like saying your route needs to be this `Route::resource('icons/{id}', 'IconController');`, because from what youve shown in your `web.php` while there is no `/icon/24` route | Also try this `php composer.phar update` | and lastly check that your `.htaccess` has the right permissions "dont change if youre unsure" and has the write code, Thats all i can give off the top of my head!

Comment: from which directory do i do the ´php composer.phar update´ ?

Comment: if you have composer installed on your server, you can use SSH to run that command on the server

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned I'm using docker. `php composer.phar update` says it cant find the file. Here they answer that you can do `composer update` which I did but that already gets done every time I send a new docker image, so that didnt fix it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355540/php-composer-phar-update-does-not-work-with-symfony-install

Comment: I am not familiar with docker so unfortunately not sure if i can help anymore! hope you get it sorted