# PHP Composer asking what program to open composer.phar file with

Tags: php, windows, composer-php

To test the Square SDK requires [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). After I installed it (on Windows) and ran the command as mentioned in the [installation instructions](https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk) which is `php composer.phar install` (and realized that the PHP bit was the *directory* and *not* part of the command; made a GIT correction on Github for that) when I run the command from the PHP directory as `composer.phar install` Windows opens up the file association dialog. This is *not* a Windows question (beyond the context that the developer machine is running Windows).

How do I install the Square SDK with Composer if Windows is asking me what program to open composer.phar file with? I am *not* running Linux.

Comment: perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441950/how-to-use-composer-on-windows

Comment: @tristansokol Got it and posted the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to download, install and run [Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/download/win).

On Windows use the `ls` command in place of `dir` to list directory contents.

When opening a directory with spaces use `cd 'my directory'`.

To get Git Bash to work with Composer navigate to the directory with the `composer.json` file. I was impressed by the attention to detail when I ran the `composer.phar install` command in a child directory and GIT Bash looked in the parent directory.

Hope this saves someone time! You can find the [original answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355540/php-composer-phar-update-does-not-work-with-symfony-install#answer-32331589) to credit the user @Junior_swashluv.